# Sphere being non contractible: physical proof?

Tags: algebraic-topology, physics

I was wondering what would be a "physicist" argument to the non contractibility of the sphere?

I am pretty sure I read something about it on internet. It used the flux of a vector field and a triple integral of a point being strictly positive, unfortunately I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://people.ucsc.edu/~lewis/Math208/hairyball.pdf) is an analytic proof due to John Milnor of the Brouwer's fixed point theorem, from which it follows that the sphere is not a retract of the disk.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237345/how-to-show-sn-is-not-contractible-without-using-homology/2156051#2156051) for why this is equivalent to noncontractibility.

Ultimately, this is just an analytic proof for a basic fact in algebraic topology, and the rest is using the theory as usual, I'm not sure exactly what you were looking for though.